# Laravel nested where using eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm using eloquent to build a query but i'm stuck in the final phase.

```
$city = City::where('name', $event)->first()->event;
```

**This is working** and returns all 3 events for this city, as shown in the screenshot

[image]

### I want to perform another where for the events, so i can select only 1 based on criteria but it's not working.

I have tried the following

```
$city = City::where('name', $event)->first()->event->where('id', 1);
```

and it's giving me the following error

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::where()
```

Comment: If it does what you want then it's probably the best method that I can tell.

Comment: Move your answer from your question to an answer and accept it when you can :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your very example makes no sense, since all you need is:

```
$eventId = 1;

Event::find($eventId);
```

In case you wanted to check if that even is related to the city:

```
Event::where('city_id', $cityId)->find($eventId); // Event model or null
```

or a bit complicated in this case, but generic solution for any relation type:

```
Event::whereHas('city', function ($q) use ($cityId) {
   $q->where('id', $cityId);
})->find($eventId); // model or null
```

And finally, if you used `find` instead of `where`:

```
City::where('name', $event)->first()->event->find(1);
City::where('name', $event)->first()->event()->find(1);
```

It would return the same `Model`.

This is because `find` it does basically the same in the context of a query builder:

```
City::where('name', $event)->first()->event()->where('id', 1)->first();
// equals to:
City::where('name', $event)->first()->event()->find(1);
```

but it is also a method of the collection:

```
$someCollection->find($someId); // returns single Model
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the `id` (1), you can do something like:

```
$city = City::where('name', $event)->where('id', 1)->first();
```

But I think you'd rather want the `city_id`:

```
$city = City::where('name', $event)->where('city_id', 3)->first();
```

Comment: Thanks Chris! I found the solution. I had get the event first using event() instead of event and then do the where on that. Thanks!

Comment: This is wrong, you don't chain different models queries like that.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

The solution is to use event()-> instead of event-> 
This query is returning the 1st record of the relationship, Which is what i needed.
Thanks everyone!

```
$city = City::where('name', $event)->first()->event()->where('id', 1)->get();
```